# How to get list of host sites and each instance of that host from arraylist of urls in java?

Tags: java, url, arraylist

I have an ArrayList with URL's as strings in it. I want to find the list of the different host sites and the number of times it appears. 
For example, if in my list there are 5 links to google i want to count them all. I was starting with a for loop iterating through each URL in the list:

```
for(int i = 0;i<list.size(); i++){

    //for every url at i identify the host site and put in hashmap where the key is the  
    //host site and the variable is the number of URL's from that host
    }
```

How would I specify the url's host (e.g. google.com) from a url string. I don't know how to code that part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that (not tested, but the principle is valid)?

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for(int i = 0;i<list.size(); i++)
    {
        URL url = new URL(list[i]);
        if (map.containsKey(url.getHost()))
        {
            map.put(url.getHost(), map.get(url.getHost()) + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            map.put(url.getHost(), 1);
        }
    }
```

If you want to print out the hash map:

```
    for (Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) 
    {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
    }
```

Comment: Just curious how I would print out the hashtable contents then. I was trying but can't seemt o do it properly. thanks btw

Comment: @user1835504 just edited my answer with a way to print out the hashmap.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use `URL.getHost()` to retrieve the host name, and a `Map<String,Integer>` to store the count of each host you see.

Answer (score 1):

Create URL object (it has a constructor that recieves a String) and use it's getHost() method

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the javadocs for URL, you will see that there is a getHost method:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html